# Substituir Base de Dados em Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6

Bom dia, estou a realizar um projeto escolar em Visual Basic 2010 com a ligação a uma base de dados Access.
Acontece que terei fazer umas alterações na Base de Dados (Acrescentar Tabelas/Campos).
Gostava de saber se consigo aproveitar o que tenho para já realizado no projeto, desde os Forms e Queries, ou se terei que fazer tudo de novo.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia TdKing, depende muito da quantidade e complexidade de alterações que terá que fazer. Não é possível saber sem ver o projeto inteiro. Você pode fazer um projeto novo e copiar e colar o que você tem certeza que está funcionando, por exemplo.